# stick image to bottom of div – responsive image issue (grid / padding)

Tags: html, css, image, responsive, padding

I've been probably overthinking this and trying out too many things incorrectly..

http://testserver.glow-berlin.de/kurzfilmwettbewerb

this is the website we're talking about. 
At the bottom (right above the footer) you find an image that is supposed to stick to the bottom of the pink box. 
Whenever I check it on mobile, the image offsets outside of the box. I built the section using the grid system but struggled with it, so I removed it for mobile... I just couldn't figure out the problem. Now – without the grid system – the same problem appears. On Android it seems to work fine but on iOS the image jumps out of the box again. When I fix it for iOS the problem appears on Android. 
Any help with this?

Comment: Nothing of what you described exist on that site.

Comment: Would be cool if you can post your code and not just ask "help me"

Comment: Quick note: it is always better to post a minimal reproduction of your code on stack overflow. Whenever someone lands on your question later, the website might already be down or changed.

Comment: You are **required** to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: Please share some code and show us what you did.

Comment: hey guys, problem has been solved in the meantime by the given answer below from Daniel. It was the "background-attachment: fixed" problem that I had in my CSS which iOS disabled. For anyone who wanted to help: sorry I didn't post the code here! But thank you all anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background-attachment: fixed;` style on your `div` with the ID `#gutfilmer` is the problem on iOS.

`'background-attachment: fixed` has been disabled on iOs since it costs a lot on mobile browsers.

If you remove it the filmflap stays on the pink background.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 #gutfilmer {
     overflow:hidden;
    }
```